# Deploying FrontEnd and BackEnd as two separate applications with Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: reactjs, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have two application that I want to deploy with Google Cloud App Engine.

One of them is react front end, and I want to serve this through MYFRONTEND.com

Second one is back-end, which will be served via api.MYBACKEND.com

Frontend yaml file react.yaml :

```
runtime: nodejs16

env: standard
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  secure: always

- url: www.MYFRONTEND.com/*
  service: frontend
  script: auto
  secure: always%
```

API yaml file, api.yaml :

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT MYAPPLICATION*emphasized text*.wsgi

service: "MYBACAKEND-api"
env: standard
handlers:

- url: api.MYBACKEND/*
  service: backend
  script: auto
  secure: always%
```

Is this the correct way to achieve this ?

What is the best strategy to serve these two separate applications that will interactively communicate (Frontend will make calls to API to get object information that is stored Django app) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google App Engine - Front and Backend Web Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077514/google-app-engine-front-and-backend-web-development)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are on the right path. You are using the [microservices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) architecture which is basically deploying individual apps as parts (services) under a single project.
2. Your frontend service seems to be your default so you don't need a service name for it. Every GAE App needs a [default service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuration-files#the_default_service).
3. Rename `react.yaml` to `app.yaml` (since it will be your default service) and update the contents to

   ```
   runtime: nodejs16

   env: standard
   handlers:
   - url: /static
     static_dir: static
     secure: always

   - url: /.*
     script: auto
     secure: always
   ```
4. Also rename your `api.yaml` to `backend.yaml` since that is what you called your service (not sure if this is required but I do that to easily track of what is controlling my service). Update the contents of the file to

   ```
   service: backend
   runtime: python37
   entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT videoo.wsgi
   env: standard

   handlers:
   - url: /.*
     script: auto
     secure: always
   ```
5. You'll need a [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) file to route traffic to the different services. Something like

```
dispatch:
  # Send all api traffic to the backend service.
  - url: "api.videoo.io/*"
    service: backend

  # Send all other traffic to the default (frontend).
  - url: "*/*"
    service: default
```

5. Final step is that during your deploy, you will deploy the 2 services in addition to your dispatch.yaml file. The dispatch.yaml file has to be in your project root folder

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml dispatch.yaml <path_to_backend.yaml>
```

Comment: In backend.yaml, replace ```api.videoo.io/*``` with ```/.*``` and see if that solves the problem. If it solves the deploy problem, deploy it and confirm the routing still works (I've upated the answer with my suggestion)

Comment: Basically, you need a URL pattern that obeys the rules for the url attribute here - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref

Comment: How would you do this if you have 16 different services, 4 for each microservice (dev, prod, etc.). all console.product.io traffic should go to the frontend, all api.product.io should go to the prod for the api service, and all other urls should simply use the default app engine urls. is this posible?

Comment: @Jul - see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine) on the max number of services you can have. See this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/NoCommandLine/199c3bbdff3a5c09de52337a5e50255c) for a sample ```dispatch.yaml``` for your situation

Comment: @NoCommandLine took a while for me to answer, but wouldn't your solution send all other traffic to the default service? For example, if I have a dev service I use for testing, which is found on something like dev-dot-frontend.appspot.etc., wouldn't traffic to that url get rerouted to the default service rather than the dev service?

Comment: @Jul In the sample [github gist](https://gist.github.com/NoCommandLine/199c3bbdff3a5c09de52337a5e50255c), I only have specific routing for ```console``` and ```api```. If you need something else, e.g. ```dev```, add an extra route before the ```default``` . If this still doesn't meet your need, you can start a chat here (on Stackoverflow) or contact us via our [website](https://nocommandline.com) and provide further details of your scenario and I'll see if I can help out.

Comment: @NoCommandLine thanks for the offer, really appreciate it! but i can't figure out how to start a chat here. i think i get it though, i guess if we have 16 different services each with their own urls that they need to be accessed from, we'd have to add 16 entries to the dispatch file? I was hoping there'd be a way to only enter the ones with custom domains where they need to be specified, and leaving the others with their default mapping, but it seems everything needs to be mapped individually