# Google App Engine: confused about routing with dispatch.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine

I'm trying to host my Spring Boot + Angular app using GAE. My server app consists of a single module called `back` (the main class is called `MyServerApplication`).

I want all the URLs containing `/api/` to end up in my Spring Boot endpoints. Here is my dispatch.yaml file:

```yaml
dispatch:
  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: XXXXXXX
```

The `XXXXXXX` is what I'm having trouble with: I can't for the life of me understand what I'm supposed to put there. I tried writing `back` or `my-server-application` to no avail. I get the following error:

```
Updating config [dispatch]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request contained an invalid argument.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Service 'my-server-application' does not exist.
    field: dispatch_rules
```

As you can see my general understanding of web hosting and of GCloud/GAE is very low, so I'm probably not clear on what "service" means here, or I'm not even supposed to use this file for routing requests.

Comment: I think you may need to read the docs to understand what a service is in the App Engine Context https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/configuration-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `dispatch.yaml`, the assumption is that your App has been broken down into smaller/individual apps and each of these Apps is viewed as a 'service'. For example a node App could be broken down into client (front-end) and back-end services. This architecture is typically referred to as [microservices](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) architecture

Each of these smaller App will have its own `app.yaml` file and the service name will be specified in the `app.yaml` file. You need to have a default service.

For a worked example and explanation, refer to my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72135525/15211203) on this Stack overflow question.

Comment: I see. My server is just one single app so it looks like I'm going in the wrong direction with `dispatch.yaml`. My goal right now is simply to reach one of my endpoints successfully (using Postman for instance) and I can't seem to do that. Shouldn't `[PROJECT_ID].[REGION].r.appspot.com/api/something` normally do the trick?

Comment: Edit: Not sure what I did, but I can reach my endpoint now, so it works!