# "Service does not exist" in App Engine dispatch.yaml file

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

I have recently gotten into GCP, and am now trying to deploy an angular frontend with a python backend, same AppEngine application but different services. The problem is that when I run `gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml`

I get

```
Updating config [dispatch]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request contained an invalid argument.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Service 'server' does not exist.
    field: dispatch_rules
```

Seems like it should be an easy fix, as I can't find any resources about it, but I just don't see it

Folder structure

```
-- appname/
---- display.yaml
---- client/
------ app.yaml (default - this one works)
------ dist/
---- server/
------ app.yaml (the troublemaker)
------ appname_backend/
```

app.yaml (the working one):

```
runtime: nodejs16

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: "appname-bucket"

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: dist/index.html
    upload: dist/index.html

  - url: /
    static_dir: dist
```

app.yaml (the one it can't find):

```
runtime: python310

env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: 'appname-bucket-backend'

service: server
```

dispatch:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "*/favicon.ico"
    service: default

  - url: "*/api/*"
    service: server
```

Documentation I have read

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/configuration-files
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/communicating-between-services
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=python

(and lots more, but these felt the most relevant)

Google reference project on Github
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/issuetracker/tree/c783a93af2c9214c13b3777a4b2da366ce65f248/services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already mentioned in one of the [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#deploying_the_dispatch_file) you shared, i.e:

> Before you deploy your dispatch file, you must ensure that all the services defined in that file have already been deployed to App Engine.

Seems like you have not created `service` named “server” yet in `App Engine`

Your frontend service seems to be your default so it’s not generating any errors.
But the service mentioned in the backend is not yet created. Hence you are getting the error

```
Updating config [dispatch]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request contained an invalid argument.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: Service 'server' does not exist.
    field: dispatch_rules
```

Deploy app using below comment which also helps to create Service for your backend.

```
gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml <path_to_backend.yaml>
```

I.e

```
gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml backend/app.yaml
```

With reference to `github` code you shared

Also check these [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72606936/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72135525/18265570) for more details